# Colorbox with iframe - closing then opening another one

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I have a colorbox window I open in an iframe. Inside that window I have a link that a user can click on and ideally I'd like the current colorbox window to close and a new colorbox window to open (again in an iframe) or load new content into the existing iframe.

My first window opens like so:

```
$.colorbox({ width: "800px", height: "580px", open: true, iframe: true, href: '/App/View?id=' + id });
```

When I click on a link in that first window this is what is fired:

```
$.colorbox({ width: "800px", height: "580px", iframe: true, href: "/App/Note?nodeId=" + nodeId })
```

I've tried to close the first window with:

```
parent.$.colorbox.close();
```

But that ends up closing both windows.

If I don't try and close the second window opens in the content of the first window and I have 2 borders, 2 close buttons etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to execute this which will close the first colorbox and then open the new colorbox with parent's context.

```
parent.$.colorbox.close(); 
parent.$.colorbox({ width: "800px", height: "580px", iframe: true, href: "/App/Note?nodeId=" + nodeId });
```

Actually you should have a function in the parent page which will do this.

```
function OpenNote(noteId){
   $.colorbox.close(); 
   $.colorbox({ width: "800px", height: "580px", iframe: true, href: "/App/Note?nodeId=" + nodeId });
}
```

And then call this function on click of the link inside View page passing the noteId.

```
parent.OpenNote(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using recursive function for open another colorbox when closed a colorbox.My function is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colorList = [];
                    colorList.push('1. Popup Content');
                    colorList.push('2. Popup Content');
                    colorList.push('3. Popup Content');
                    colorList.push('4. Popup Content');
            colorboxRecursive(colorList);
    function colorboxRecursive(colorList){
        if (colorList.length>0) {
            $.colorbox({
                html:colorList.pop(),
                onClosed:function(){
                    if (colorList.length>0)
                        colorboxRecursive(colorList);
                }
            });
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```